# I downloaded a 32 bit program on a 64 bit system

Tags: windows-10, 32-vs-64-bit

Did not notice until already running, downloaded a 32 bit program on a 64 bit system. Would I get better results installing the 64 bit program, or keep the 32 bit program and run it?

Comment: That's going to depend on the program, and specifically what system components (e.g., DLLs) it interacts with. As an example, you wouldn't want to install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Office if you want to use many add-ons; most add-ons haven't been rebuilt to be compatible with 64-bit Office.

Answer (score 1):

There is no harm in running a 32 bit program on a 64 bit system.  More than likely you will not even notice a difference between a 32 and a 64 bit version of the program.  The biggest advantage of 64 bit programs is the ability to use more than 2GB of memory.  Unless your application is memory hungry, there is no need to upgrade.  Also, in some rare cases, 64 bit applications can run *slower* than 32 bit applications.